# How can websocket broadcast be implemented with http4k?

Tags: kotlin, websocket, broadcast, http4k

I'm building a small websocket app with [http4k websocket](https://www.http4k.org/cookbook/websockets/) and looks like there is no documentation about how to implement message broadcasting with it (*i.e.* react to a message sending it to all the clients except the one that sent the message). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "does http4k ship with an entire distributed messaging platform", then the answer is no :) . However, if you just want to have a single messaging node which keeps track of all of the messages and connected websockets in memory, then it's quite simple to do.

This code is adapted from an [http4k demo project](https://github.com/daviddenton/http4k-demo-irc) which implements a chat server in 30 lines of Kotlin:

```
fun IrcApp(): PolyHandler {
    val userCounter = AtomicInteger()
    val participants = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Websocket>()

    fun newConnection(ws: Websocket) {
        val id = "user${userCounter.incrementAndGet()}"
        participants += id to ws
        ws.onMessage { new ->
            participants.values
                .filterNot { it == ws }
                .forEach { it.send(WsMessage("$id: ${new.bodyString()}")) }
        }
        ws.onClose {
            participants -= id
        }
    }

    return PolyHandler(
        static(ResourceLoader.Classpath()),
        websockets("/ws" bind ::newConnection)
    )
}
```